# Allocating and releasing a class object

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a little beginner Question, for example in my ViewDidLoad method i want to allocate a new class object, execute a few methods in that new class and then release it:

```
Calibration *cali = [[Calibration alloc] initWithMainViewController:self];

[cali doCalibration];

[cali release];
```

So why is this not working?! Why is it giving me an Crash with Bad Access?!

Btw: Please don´t advise me to use ARC. I´m working on an existing Project which was started without ARC

EDIT:

Stacktrace: [CFRunLoopTimer invalidate]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xc2436d0

Comment: What is going on in initWithMainViewController: method? May be some deallocation staff? Where do you get a crash (at what line of code)?

Comment: If there is a problem in your code, it isn't in this question. You need to set an exception breakpoint, and look at which point the crash happens. Include that code and the stack trace in the question. And use ARC ;)

Comment: @opedge you were right...I invalidated a timer object twice...:/ Thx for the hint...

Answer (score 0):

Well short answer crash will occur when the variable is released and if try to access the same it will crash. So for avoiding this, just declare the instance variable in .h file and use dealloc method in .m file inside that release your instance variable. Below is the dealloc method, declare the same in .m file.

```
-(void)dealloc
{
[cali release];
 }
```